# Python multiprocessing slow with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, python-multiprocessing

I have a very processor-intensive task that takes a ballpark of 13-20 hours to complete, depending on the machine. Seemed like an obvious choice for parallelization via the multiprocessing library. Problem is... the more processes I spawn, the slower the same code gets.

Time per iteration (i.e. the time it takes to run sparse.linalg.cg):

> 183s 1 process
>
> 245s 2 processes
>
> 312s 3 processes
>
> 383s 4 processes

Granted, while 2 processes takes a little over 30% more time for each iteration, it's doing 2 at the same time, so it's still marginally faster. But I would not expect the actual math operations themselves to be slower! These timers don't start until after whatever overhead multiprocessing adds.

Here's a stripped down version of my code. The problem line is the sparse.linalg.cg one. (I've tried things like using MKL vs OpenBLAS, and forcing them to run in a single thread. Also tried manually spawning Processes instead of using a pool. No luck.)

```
def do_the_thing_partial(iteration: int, iter_size: float, outQ : multiprocessing.Queue, L: int, D: int, qP: int, elec_ind: np.ndarray, Ic: int, ubi2: int,
                 K : csc_matrix, t: np.ndarray, dip_ind_t: np.ndarray, conds: np.ndarray, hx: float, dstr: np.ndarray):
    range_start = ceil(iteration * iter_size)
    range_end = ceil((iteration + 1) * iter_size)

    for rr in range(range_start, range_end):
        # do some things (like generate F from rr)
        Vfull=sparse.linalg.cg(K,F,tol=1e-11,maxiter=1200)[0] #Solve the system
        # do more things
        outQ.put((rr, Vfull))


def do_the_thing(L: int, D: int, qP: int, elec_ind: np.ndarray, Ic: int, ubi2: int,
                 K : csc_matrix, t: np.ndarray, dip_ind_t: np.ndarray, conds: np.ndarray, hx: float, dstr: np.ndarray):
    num_cores = cpu_count()
    iterations_per_process = (L-1) / num_cores  # 257 / 8 ?

    outQ = multiprocessing.Queue()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores)

    [pool.apply_async(do_the_thing_partial,
                      args=(i, iterations_per_process, outQ, L, D, qP, elec_ind, Ic, ubi2, K, t, dip_ind_t, conds, hx, dstr),
                      callback=None)
     for i in range(num_cores)]

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    for res in outQ:
        # combine results and return here
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it impossible to parallelize sparse.linalg.cg because of its own optimizations?

Thanks!

Comment: Explain how you are splitting the task up among processes.  `cg` is solving `K*x=F` iteratively.  What's different between processes?

Comment: F is defined in the 'do some things' section, which is calculated using rr. The range of values that are possible for rr to be depends on which process

For instance, with 2 processes:
Process 0: rr is in range 0..127
Process 1: rr is in range 128..255

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of how to get a speedup using [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) (a library for parallel and distributed Python). You can run the code below after doing `pip install ray` (on Linux or MacOS).

Running the serial version of the computation below (e.g., doing `scipy.sparse.linalg.cg(K, F, tol=1e-11, maxiter=100)` 20 times) takes **33 seconds** on my laptop. Timing the code below for launching the 20 tasks and getting the results takes **8.7 seconds**. My laptop has 4 physical cores, so this is almost a **4x speedup**.

I changed your code a lot, but I think I preserved the essence of it.

```
import numpy as np
import ray
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg

# Consider passing in 'num_cpus=psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)'.
ray.init()

num_elements = 10**7
dim = 10**4

data = np.random.normal(size=num_elements)
row_indices = np.random.randint(0, dim, size=num_elements)
col_indices = np.random.randint(0, dim, size=num_elements)

K = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((data, (row_indices, col_indices)))

@ray.remote
def solve_system(K, F):
    # Solve the system.
    return scipy.sparse.linalg.cg(K, F, tol=1e-11, maxiter=100)[0]

# Store the array in shared memory first. This is optional. That is, you could
# directly pass in K, however, this should speed it up because this way it only
# needs to serialize K once. On the other hand, if you use a different value of
# "K" for each call to "solve_system", then this doesn't help.
K_id = ray.put(K)

# Time the code below!

result_ids = []
for _ in range(20):
    F = np.random.normal(size=dim)
    result_ids.append(solve_system.remote(K_id, F))

# Run a bunch of tasks in parallel. Ray will schedule one per core.
results = ray.get(result_ids)
```

The call to `ray.init()` starts the Ray worker processes. The call to `solve_system.remote` submits the tasks to the workers. Ray will schedule one per core by default, though you can specify that a particular task requires more resources (or fewer resources) via `@ray.remote(num_cpus=2)`. You can also specify GPU resources and other custom resources.

The call to `solve_system.remote` immediately returns an ID representing the eventual output of the computation, and the call to `ray.get` takes the IDs and retrieves the actual results of the computation (so `ray.get` will wait until the tasks finish executing).

**Some notes**

- On my laptop, `scipy.sparse.linalg.cg` seems to limit itself to a single core, but if it doesn't, then you should consider pinning each worker to a specific core to avoid contention between worker processes (you can do this on Linux by doing `psutil.Process().cpu_affinity([i])` where `i` is the index of the core to bind to.
- If the tasks all take variable amounts of time, make sure that you aren't just waiting for one really slow task. You can check this by running `ray timeline` from the command line and visualizing the result in chrome://tracing (in the Chrome web browser).
- Ray uses a [shared memory object store](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/plasma.html) to avoid having to serialize and deserialize the `K` matrix once per worker. This is an important performance optimization (though it doesn't matter if the tasks take a really long time). This helps primarily with objects that contain large numpy arrays. It doesn't help with arbitrary Python objects. This is enabled by using the [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) data layout. You can read more in [this blog post](https://ray-project.github.io/2017/10/15/fast-python-serialization-with-ray-and-arrow.html).

You can see more in the [Ray documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Note that I'm one of the Ray developers.

Comment: By the way, you probably want to use `import psutil` and then `num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)` to count physical cores (which is the relevant count for numerical workloads). Then you can do `ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus)`.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the effort you put into this response (Ray seems pretty cool!), but I'm having the same problem with Ray that I was with Multiprocessing. Likely due to worker contention, as you said

using different values for num_cpus in ray.init, I get the following timings for how long it takes to run one iteration of *just* the cg:
1 process: 225 seconds
2 process: 291 seconds
4 process: 460 seconds

Granted, 4 processes calculates 4 at once, so it's sorta 115 seconds per solve, but there's got to be some way to run cg (even w/ another library) in parallel without cg slowing down

Comment: A couple thoughts: 1) did you try pinning workers to specific different cores (e.g., using `psutil.Process().cpu_affinity`, and are you sure that each process is using at most one core (e.g., check `top`)? 2) How many CPU cores do you have? There is an important distinction between physical and virtual. Your results make sense if you have only 2 physical cores (what does `psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)` return? 3) You won't get a perfect speedup if the task durations are variable (you'll end up waiting for the slowest one). Could that be going on here?

Comment: Well, it looks like you were right about CPU affinity and pinning. Unfortunately, there's no mac-compatible equivalent, but I was able to confirm on a slower linux box that there were more predictable semi-linear speedups with more cores once I manually pinned to different cores.